# Proper design to parse file in c++

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm trying to parse a file and store the different fields in some variable.
However, I'm not sure of the proper design to do this:

Should I have a class for parsing and a class for storage, or should the parser also be used as storage to hold the fields ?

I also have to keep in mind that I might need to extend the parser as new fields may appear in the file.

**Edit:** It has been mentionned that the question was too broad. I included more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419582/is-my-c-pattern-design-flawed-for-parsing-file) but I didn't want to influence the answers with what I already implemented. In my current implementation I faced some issues to extended the parser, and someone pointed out that I shouldn't separate data storage and parser (because of the single responsibility principle) but for me it made sense to separate them.

Comment: Too broad question. Add more details and put real question in place.

Comment: I'm not sure which details you want me to provide. I could reformulate like this: What are the pros and cons of having a separated class (from the parser) to store the data ?

Comment: Good design is driven by the SOLID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) principles. The first one from that list is named **single responsibility principle**. Maybe that helps you to decide what to do. Besides: you can't provide "more" details that would make sense; as your whole question in itself is too broad. Stackoverflow is about **specific** programming problems; not about "here are a few requirements; and you tell me the best way to do that".

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of necessity. If your problem is likely to stay small, put the parsing and storage together. You'll have to have the parsed data somewhere in memory regardless, so why not right where it comes in?

The main reason you'd want to separate them is if you need to store in different ways, such as database or file, and you need some sort of interface that can deal with extensibility.

But think about that only if it looks likely to come up.

Comment: Thank you. The main reason why I asked this question is because originally I separated the storage and parser, but someone told me that this is not an appropriate design because in OOP objects are responsible for themselve, but I wasn't sure to understand how to apply this advice here.

Comment: I don't think this is a question of necessity. One always designs in a way that those parts of a system that are likely to change ... can be changed. And unless this is a really small, very short lived parser ... separating responsibilities into more than one component seems like an absolute must.